# Autoresponder in Gmail for one particular address (TO this address, not FROM)

Tags: gmail, automation

I use Gmail to work with my external POP3 accounts as well. I want to use one of them just as an autoresponding address (because I stopped working for this company but still receive emails which I don't want to block. I want to let them know that they should contact other persons of this company. Unfortunately the server config of the company doesn't allow serverside autoresponding services).

What can I do to make Gmail autorespond with a predefined message if the email goes to this address.

Better explained:

If email is to:example@blablabla.com then autorespond with "blah".

I just know how to set a general autoresponder - but that one autoresponds to EVERY mail when enabled.